# How to monitor and alert on sparse event data?

Tags: time-series, monitoring

To give you an idea of what I'm dealing with, I calculated the average time between events for each of our customers. The lowest is 24 seconds and the highest is 689,014 seconds. Yes, 7 days.

I'm building a single dashboard that monitors all these events and will eventually alert when a feed is "down". This poses an obvious problem.
Right now what I'm doing is getting the last 50 events and using the difference between the oldest one and now to establish a "threshold" of sorts. I'm then saying "how many messages sent during threshold". If this hits zero, I consider it an alarm.

I'm sure there's a better way to do this. What is it? Maybe use the average-time-between-events above + 50% or something? I doubt there's some magic number, but any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a good approach for this?

Comment: I found an acceptable approach, but it was so complex and so long ago I can't really help you :(  Definitely see the PDF in the answer below though.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment but I don't have enough reputation points to post one. Here's a link to a pdf with a really thorough workup of "data mining for rare events." It should provide some direction...

http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~aleks/pakdd04_tutorial.pdf

Comment: This made my brain melt, but a few cells were able to at least identify some new terms to search on which has led to some good information.  Thanks for the start!